# positively identify remote devices on network

Tags: wireless, byod

From time to time looking at network logs i see strange devices on the network. I will nmap them and get "tcwrapped" tcp ports 2000 & 5060 these are indicative of a voip device. The logs indicate its actively going out bound on port 80. this happens alot. So my question is how can i positivity identify the example above are in fact android devices. Ive tried scanning my own phone and get diff results. which just adds to the confusion.

PS: i cant go to locations and to many wireless devies

[Link port 5060](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=5060)

[Link port 2000](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=2000)

Comment: In most cases, it's more important to positively identify users than identify devices.  Strong user authentication is better than positive machine identification

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 100% definitive method other than actually finding the thing, but there are various clues.

1. What is the vendor in it's MAC address? what does that vendor make?
2. Where is it connecting to? lots of public websites? (implies someone or something browsing the web) lots of IPs in dynamic ISP space? (implies peer to peer activity) a small handful of destinations (implies something more single-purpose)
3. What does the timing of the traffic look like? if it's regular it's probablly something automated, it it's more sporadic then it's more likely user-driven.
4. You say the connectivity is over port 80, is it actually http or some random protocol over port 80? if it is http what is the user agent?
5. Is there also traffic to port 443? if a user is browsing the modern web then one would expect traffic to both ports 80 and 443, 80 only is more likely something more special-purpose.

Comment: the net logs i have dont not record the MAC and i dont have access to pcaps to get the user agent. assuming thats how u get it with out logs.

Comment: alos was http/80 and no 443/https pretty consistent so could have been automated. hell could even be an update but the public info on the ip its going to doesnt give you that feel

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is how can i positivity identify the example above are
>   in fact android devices.

Bottom line:  you can't, especially given the restrictions you mention in @petergreen 's answer.  The best you can do is make an educated guess.  Depending on your goal, a guess may be good enough answer.  Don't let the quest for perfection stop you from doing something useful.

If you have access to wireless controllers or access switches, you can get the MAC address that way.

Comment: got a pcap access from fw directly. its a cisco voip devices so now just to figure out if these things typically talk outbound through the web